# How does importing within Swift work?

Tags: swift

If I want to use Quartz and I type

```
import QuartzCore
```

for some reason, it works. If I type anything else, it doesn't work. When I check the documentation (Command click), it is a blank header file. How do I import headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs, import **works for any Objective-C framework (or C library) that is accessible as a module**.Objective-C frameworks vend APIs in header files. In Swift, those header files are compiled down to Objective-C modules, which are then imported into Swift as Swift APIs.